# GIS system for displaying GDSII(*.gds) format?

Tags: convert, layers, file-formats, software-recommendations

I want to display vector graphics on raster graphics and I have vector scheme in [GDSII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDSII) format.

There are some viewers for GDSII like [KLayout](http://www.klayout.de/intro.html) for example, but they don't support raster graphics.

Is there any out-the-box solution? If no, if I know how to parse my vector graphics(for example I can get lines or polygons) can I somehow convert them to some format that some GIS system takes?

Comment: I see Sketchup has a [GDSII importer](https://sites.google.com/site/sketchupsage/resources) available (search GDSII on that page). You might be able to pull it into there and then export an more GIS consumable format. All other references I see are to highly specialized oil and gas software. The two big translators I know of, FME and Esri Data Interoperability, don't mention it in supported formats.